# Perl: Need a dynamic substitution in the variable string, and not during parsing

Tags: perl, interpreter

```
my @banks = @banksDup= ("abs", "qer", "qaz");
my $serverFailedabs;
my $serverFailedqer;
my $serverFailedqaz;

### Some processing of $serverFailedabs, $serverFailedqer and $serverFailedqaz happens here ###

foreach my $bank (@banks) {
        if("$serverFailed${bank}" ne "")    ## Line 85
        {
                print "$bank server setup failed;
                @banksDup = grep !/${bank}/, @banksDup;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Global symbol "$serverFailed" requires explicit package name at perl1.pl line 85
```

Here, "$serverFailed${bank}" is being considered as $serverFailed in the parsing stage, and giving error. How can I avoid this issue?

I want that "$serverFailed${bank}" is executed during execution so that "$serverFailed${bank}" gets correct value

Comment: Learn how to use _associative array_ instead of testing wrong code

Comment: For some background on why this approach is bad and why using a hash was recommended, read [this](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Comment: @GillesQuenot: The Perl community switched to calling them "hashes" when Perl 5 was released in 1994.

Comment: I guess OP don't know hash, so associative array is another way to talk about hash. Just my thought. But yes, in Perl, it's a hash :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a hash.

```perl
my @banks = ( "abs", "qer", "qaz" );
my @banksDup = @banks;

my %serverFailed = (
  abs => '',
  qer => '',
  qaz => '',
);

for my $bank ( @banks ) {
   if ( $serverFailed{$bank} ne "" ) {
      print "$bank server setup failed\n";
      @banksDup = grep $_ ne $bank, @banksDup;
   }
}
```